# How do I replace an ActiveRecord association member in-memory and then save the association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `has_may` `through` association and I'm trying to change records in the association *in memory* and then have all the associations updated in a single transaction on `#save`. I can't figure out how to make this work.

Here's a simplifiction of what I'm doing (using the popular Blog example):

```
# The model
class Users < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, through: user_posts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts
end

# The controller
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def update
    user.assign_attributes(user_params)
    replace_existing_posts(user)
    user.save
  end

  private

  def replace_existing_posts(user)
    user.posts.each do |post|
      existing = Post.find_by(title: post.title)
      next unless existing
      post.id = existing
      post.reload
    end
  end
end
```

This is a bit contrived. The point is that if a post that the user added already exists in the system, we just assign the existing post to them. If the post does not already exist we create a new one.

The problem is, that when I call `user.save` it saves any *new* posts (and the `user_post` association) but doesn't create the `user_post` association for the existing record.

I've tried to resolve this by adding `has_many :user_posts, autosave: true` to the `User` model, but despite the [documented statement](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html) "When `:autosave` is true all children are saved", that doesn't reflect the behavior I see.

I can make this work, with something hacky like this, but I don't want to save the association records separately (and removing and replacing all associations would lead to lots of callback I don't want to fire).

```
posts = user.posts.to_a
user.posts.reset
user.posts.replace(posts)
```

I've trolled through the ActiveRecord docs and the source code and haven't found a way to add records to a `has_many through` association that create the mapping record in memory.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this to work, just by adding the association records manually.

So now my controller also does this in the update:

```
user.posts.each do |post|
  next unless post.persisted?
  user.user_posts.build(post: post)
end
```

Posting this as an answer unless someone has a better solution.